# How to add provisioning profile to IPA file

Tags: ios, ipa

I downloaded an IPA off the web and I want to upload it to [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) or [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) for demo testing, but I keep getting errors like `No provisioning profile found in the application bundle` or `Invalid IPA: missing embedded provisioning profile. Are you sure this is an ad hoc?`

How can I edit the IPA so I can successfully upload them to the demo sites?

PS: I don't have XCode.

Comment: I know utest.com does it for us but I'm not sure how.  We deliver them an IPA and they add their own provisioning profiles to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

When the `.ipa` was built, it had to have been built with a provisioning profile in order to be distributed.  In addition, your test device's UDID has to be on the list of valid devices for that provisioning profile.  Once the `.ipa` has been created, you can't go back and edit it.  If you want to be able to run it on your device, you need to create a new one--or have the original person who created the `.ipa` make a new one, since you don't have XCode.

Comment: TestFlight seems to be able to update the provisioning profile associated with an .ipa file.

Comment: @WiseShepherd This would be amazing it if worked, please explain

Answer (score 0):

You can not sign .IPA file with any other way, you need to prepare new build signed with updated provisioning profile, where devices ID's are included in it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that while creating an **.ipa** file you must need to select **Generic iOS Device** as a **[image: Target]**